# Creating a win form label in c# code using variable?

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, label

I have this code to create a new label with a variable attached to it but I get an error (obviously).  Is there a way to do this?

```
System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl_Task[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
```

I.e, if i == 4, the label would be called lbl_Task4.  If i == 9, it would be lbl_Task9, etc.

Edit:

New code shows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            //create a label for the Task Name
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Name = "lbl_Task" + i;
            tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(lbl, 4);
            lbl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            lbl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, pointInt);
            lbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 24);
            lbl.TabIndex = 8;
            lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(dtTasks.Rows[i]["Task_Name"]);
            lbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

            this.Controls.Add(lbl);
            pointInt += 24;
        }
```

This compiles but does not show on my win form when I debug.  Any ideas?

Comment: instead of relying on Label's name, use [Control.Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property to store `i`, The way you are creating label is wrong. Should be like: `System.Windows.Forms.Label lbl_Task = new System.Windows.Forms.Label(); lbl_Task.Tag = i;`

Comment: Don't write code like this, it performs *very* poorly beyond getting it wrong.  Use a ListBox or ListView instead.

Comment: You are going to have to document what you are doing with that TableLayoutPanel control and how the Label controls relate to it.

Comment: What @HansPassant says, or GDI+ it.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't write code like this, however it was an experiment to see if it could be done this way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
{
   Label lbl = new Label();
   lbl.Name = "lbl_Task" + i;
   // set other properties
   this.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a collection of Lables and try like this

```
List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Label label = new Label();
    // Set Lable properties

    yourLayoutName.Controls.Add(label);//add the lable
    labels.Add(label);
}
```